# Ubuntu 17.04 unable to contect to external monitor

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, 17.04

Just upgraded to 17.04 from 16.10 and my external monitor is not recognized. Checked the display settings, no external monitor is showing up. In my previous upgrades from 14.04 to 16.10, my external monitor is recognized.

Hardware platform is a Dell XPS M1330 with a NVIDA GeForce 8400M video card connected via VGA cable to a Dell S2440L monitor. I have to use the monitor given the fact my XPS laptop display is not functioning correctly.

At boot time I noticed the NVIDA logo does not show up, previously it did. Are my nvida drivers gone awol? Did the upgrade remove them?

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: *"my XPS laptop display is not functioning correctly"* - Meaning it's physically broken, or Ubuntu isn't playing nicely with it?

Comment: Yes, the upgrade most likely removed the Nvidia drivers. Please go to Settings > Additional drivers, check and (re)apply if needed. Reboot and test. Obs.: You should see there the 340 version only. There's currently no other for your hardware.

Comment: physically broken laptop monitor.

Comment: Managed to download drivers,  external monitor now functional.